# CSS Animated icons appearing on page load and popping in before animating properly

Tags: javascript, css, animation, css-animations

I'm trying to create a draft for a mobile website interface but I'm having some strange issues with the menu. Initially when the page loads it should display a blank footer except for a plus icon. When clicked, the plus icon expands and various other icons pop up that link to different parts of the interface. However, when I load the page these icons are visible. Further, when I try to expand and shrink the menu bar for the first time they disappear. However, if I then expand it again they pop in for a moment before vanishing then expanding like I expect.

I'm not sure why the transition effect works one way and not the other. I've tried messing with the timing of the opacity and visibility properties in the keyframes but so far it's still displaying this weird behavior. I've also tried adding a class that makes the elements hidden on page load and removing it the first time they're animating but that doesn't fix the pop in on subsequent cycles. I've included the relevant sections of the code below and a [codepen](https://codepen.io/Ken-MR/pen/MWqwpma) of everything. I've slowed down the icon animations for the moment so it's easier to see their behavior.

JS

```
const mobile_menu = (() => {
  const expandNavigation = (navButton, navBar, buttons) => {
    navButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
      let buttonType = ['slow', 'fast', 'fast', 'slow'];
      if (navButton.classList.contains('clicked')) {
        navButton.classList.add('unclicked');
        navButton.classList.remove('clicked');

        navBar.classList.add('retract');
        navBar.classList.remove('expand');

        for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
          showButton(buttons[i], buttonType, 'retract');
        }
      }
      else {
        navButton.classList.add('clicked');
        navButton.classList.remove('unclicked');
        
        navBar.classList.add('expand');
        navBar.classList.remove('retract');

        for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
          showButton(buttons[i], buttonType, 'expand');
        }
      }
    });
  }

  const showButton = (button, type, direction) => {
    if (direction === 'retract') {
      if (type === 'slow') {
        button.classList.remove('icon_appear_slow');
        button.classList.add('icon_vanish_slow');
      }
      else {
        button.classList.remove('icon_appear_fast');
        button.classList.add('icon_vanish_fast');
      }
    }
    else {
      if (type === 'slow') {
        button.classList.remove('icon_vanish_slow');
        button.classList.add('icon_appear_slow');
      }
      else {
        button.classList.remove('icon_vanish_fast');
        button.classList.add('icon_appear_fast');
      }
    }
  }

  return { expandNavigation };
})();
```

HTML

```
    <div class="screen">
      <div class="page">Content</div>
      <div class="nav_menu">
        <span id="nav_bar"></span>
        <div class="nav_button">
          <i class = "material-icons call">call</i>
        </div>
        <div class="nav_button">
          <i class = "material-icons message">chat</i>         
        </div>
        <div class="nav_icon">
          <i id="open_close" class = "material-icons unclicked">add</i>
        </div>
        <div class="nav_button">
          <i class = "material-icons account">person</i>
        </div>
        <div class="nav_button">
          <i class = "material-icons settings">settings</i>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.icon_appear_slow {
  animation: grow 1s ease-in-out 2s 1 normal forwards;
}

.icon_appear_fast {
  animation: grow 2s ease-in-out 1s 1 normal forwards;
}

.icon_vanish_slow {
  animation: shrink 1s ease-in-out 2s 1 normal forwards;
}

.icon_vanish_fast {
  animation: shrink 2s ease-in-out 1s 1 normal forwards;
}

@keyframes grow {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.1);
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  1% {
    visibility: visible;
  }

  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg) scale(1);;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes shrink {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1);
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
  }

  99% {
    visibility: hidden;
  }

  100% {
    transform: rotate(-360deg) scale(0.1);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `id="nav_bar"` to `class="nav_bar"`
i dont really know but its not saving the changes with id

on the js part:
just change `const navBar = document.getElementById('nav_bar');`
to
`const navBar = document.querySelector('.nav_bar');`

on the css part:

```
.retract {
  height: 60px;
  width: 350px;
  animation: retraction 0.3s ease-in-out 2.5s 1 normal forwards;
}
.icon_vanish_fast {
  opacity:1;
  animation: shrink 2s ease-in-out 1s 1 normal forwards;
}
.icon_vanish_slow {
  opacity:1;
  animation: shrink 1s ease-in-out 2s 1 normal forwards;
}
.nav_bar {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  background: rgb(30, 134, 30);
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
}
.nav_button {
  opacity:0;
}
```